# How do I ack messages with RabbitMQ and Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, rabbitmq, spark-streaming

I receive messages from a RabbitMQ broker.

How do I issue an ack or nack, inside a Spark action (like foreach/foreachPartition), to retry message processing at a later time or just discard it?

I can't just pass along the deliveryTag, connect to rabbit inside an action and send the ack, since the deliveryTag is bound to a particular channel.

Comment: What does Spark have to do with your problem? More specifically, you tagged as Spark-Streaming. Perhaps you need to add more details about your problem.

Comment: Maybe your use case is one in which you have a driver node receiving messages from the queue and creating distributed tasks: one for each message. Then tasks would need to ack or nack messages depending on some condition checked during the task execution. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Something like that.
i have a receiver that pops messages from RabbitMQ.
Then, It does an "store" of the message.
What I need is the ability to ack/nack that message inside a Spark action (like foreach/foreachPartition)

Now, the problem is that I can't just connect to RabbitMQ and send a nack frame to the broker because the id of the message is bound to the channel that belongs to the connection that receiver has. You follow?

Answer (score 1):

Spark tasks typically run on remote nodes. So all objects on the context that a task interacts with should be either private to the task or [shared variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables). RabbitMQ connection objects (any sort of connection, actually) established on the driver node will not be carried to remote nodes. Therefore in order to send ack and noack to RabbitMQ you need to do it outside of tasks, unless you are running everything on the driver node.

In short, try to find a way to signal message consumption failures back to the driver node and have the driver node send all acks and noacks.